# Pantalla en negro al intentar instalar ArchLinux

Tags: linux, instalacion, archlinux

Soy un poco nuevo en el tema de linux, ya tenia instalado Ubuntu 21.04 y todo estaba prefectamente pero de repente al inicar el sistema se quedaba en negro porque lo que decidi desinstarlo, y reinstalar, pero seguia saliendo lo mismo y no me dejaba ver nada mas que una pantalla negra por bastante tiempo

Por este motivo decidi instalar ArchLinux pero al iniciar el instalador de este se queda en negro y no aparece nada mas que eso

Estoy lo estoy haciendo dualboot junto Windows 11, pero no puedo instalar ninguna distribucion de Linux

Gracias

Comment: Y si tratas de correr el instalador en modo texto?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hace mucho se me presente ese mismo error con ubuntu, logre solucionarlo de esta manera, aun guardaba en marcadores la página https://blog.desdelinux.net/solucionado-ubuntu-se-cuelga-al-inicio-pantalla-negravioleta-de-la-muerte/

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.